# Typescript define subclass mapping and create subclass at runtime

Tags: typescript

I have 3 classes definition A, B and C where B & C both extends abstract class A.

```
abstract class A {
  public name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  abstract getName(): string;
}

class B extends A {
  getName(): string {
    return "B: " + this.name;
  }
}

class C extends A {
  getName(): string {
    return "C: " + this.name;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create subclass of an abstract class at runtime as of the below code. However it results in an compiler error: "Cannot create an instance of abstract class"

```
const classes: { [type: string]: typeof A } = {
  b: B,
  c: C,
};

function test(type: string, name: string) {
  if (!classes.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid type: ${type}`);
  }
  const _class = classes[type];
  return new _class("name");  // compiler error: Cannot create an instance of abstract class.
}

let x = test("b", "bob");
console.log(x.getName());
```

If I change the `classes` definition to `{ [type: string]: typeof B | typeof C }` it works.

```
const classes: { [type: string]: typeof B | typeof C } = {
  b: B,
  c: C,
};

function test(type: string, name: string) {
  if (!classes.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid type: ${type}`);
  }
  const _class = classes[type];
  return new _class("name");
}

let x = test("b", "bob");
console.log(x.getName());
```

But this way the definition will grow really quick e.g. `typeof B | typeof C | typeof D | typeof E | etc.` Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type the map value as a constructor taking `string` input and returning `A`:

```
type AConstructor = new (name: string) => A;

const classes: { [type: string]: AConstructor } = {
  b: B,
  c: C,
};
```