# Typing dynamic map of classes

Tags: typescript, class, export

I have a function that can modify a given class dynamically ([inspired by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687631/type-definition-for-a-function-returning-extended-anonymous-class)):

```js
interface Constructable {
    new (...args: any[]): any;
}

function extendClass<T extends Constructable>(Base: T, customConfig: object): T {
    return class extends Base {
      constructor(...options: any[]) {
        super({ ...options, ...customConfig });
      }
    };
};
```

Such that I can do this:

```js
class A {
  constructor({ x, y }: { x?:number, y?:number } ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  incrementX() {
    this.x += 1
  }
}

const B = extendClass(A, { y: 6 })

const b = new B({x:5})
```

How can I create a function to do this across a map of classes while keeping the typing information ie:

```js
type DictionaryOfConstructors<T extends Constructable> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };


function extendAll<T>(classes: DictionaryOfConstructors<T>, customConfig: object) {
  const updated = {}

  Object.entries(services).forEach(([k, s]) => {
    updated[k] = extendClass(s, customConfig);
  });

  return updated;
}

const classes = { A };

const extended = extendAll(classes, { y: 6 })
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323917/typescript-define-subclass-mapping-and-create-subclass-at-runtime/50324065) seemed related, but it isnt dynamic

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  It appears that you could develop a factory which creates an instance of the external library class and set the necessary props.

Comment: I use a factory function to modify imported classes, basically assign one of their internal properties so the user doesnt have to. But when i exported these wrappers, they lost all their type information. So basically i did what you mentioned, i just couldnt get the types to work properly. Here is the current [code](https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker/blob/master/packages/gitbeaker-node/src/index.ts) (I tried to simplify it a bit in the description)

Comment: In the GitHub example, your factory is returning an object with instantiated objects, so the example above `const a:A = new A()` will never work because `A` is already an instance.  Do you really need to create 94 instances of objects?  Instead could the classes in instantiated as needed?  For example: `const gitlab = myServiceFactory(Gitlab);` then `myServiceFactory` will implement the same logic you have in `modifyServices`.

Comment: It returns a [function](https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker/blob/1997e3416e90406902bf13ec1da74d50e1818db0/packages/gitbeaker-requester-utils/src/RequesterUtils.ts#L88), not an instantiated class. The function .. wait maybe I could change that from a function to a class that extends the original class, but sets one of the internal properties in the constructor. Ill give it a try!

Originally did have something similar to what you mentioned, but then i was stuck without being able to do named exports

Comment: @Paul I updated the question, should be clearer now!

Comment: I'm still confused with one detail.  Are you looking to dynamically declare properties?  In your examples, you have `class A` which has properties `x`, and `y`.  In your consumer examples, you're setting either property `x`, or `y` (ex: `const B = extendClass(A, { y: 6 })`).  This isn't really extending a class, it's just a factory-like pattern that presets existing properties.  Are you saying you could set the non-existing property `z` with `const C = extendClass(A, { z: 123 })`?

Comment: @Paul It was just an example, it is simply a factory pattern, but I was trying to maintain the correct typing. As for your last example, no I wouldnt be setting a non-existing property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a modified version of the `externalFactory`.  There's commented out examples at the which verify type-checking.

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-thunder-u83b6?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: How could this be modified such that it runs the factory on all the values in this object while maintaining the typing? Like I mentioned in the last code snippet with extendAll?

Comment: @JustinDalrymple, I just updated the answer with a new sandbox link.  The `extendAll` factory and consumer example is at the bottom.

Comment: Just looking over the work now, it seems only one of the classes is being typed correctly, since when i write this:

const bb = factories.ExternalB([{ propB: 345 }]);

It still comes out as ExternalA type.

Comment: Im trying to get an output like:



const s2: {
    ExternalA: typeof ExternalA;
    ExternalB: typeof ExternalB;
}

Is that even possible, without explicitly typing everything

Comment: I'll look into the `ExternalA` issue in your first comment.  Can you clarify your `s2` comment?  I don't understand what `s2` is suppose to represent.

Comment: It was just a variable name sorry. I think i figured it out, testing it now. Ill post the results in a few hours or so

Answer (score 0):

For added examples, this is what I ended up using:

```js
export interface Constructable<T = {}> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function extendClass<T extends Constructable>(Base: T, customConfig: object): T {
  return class extends Base {
    constructor(...options: any[]) {
      const [config, ...opts] = options;

      super({ ...config, ...customConfig }, ...opts);
    }
  };
}

export function extendAll<T extends { [name: string]: Constructable }>(
  class: T,
  customConfig: object,
) {
  const updated: { [name: string]: Constructable } = {};

  Object.entries(classes).forEach(([k, s]) => {
    updated[k] = extendClass(s, customConfig);
  });

  return updated as T;
}

// And the use case:
const modifiedClasses = extendAll(classes, { propA: 5 });
```